# Building an inbox system using Express/MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have been developing an app for renting flats for a personal project of mine. I have been wondering about how to build/implement an inbox system to the current app which uses mongodb as database.

What does matter in such a feature? Would it be possible to define a schema called messages ?

```
var MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  message: String,
  sender : {
        id : {
            type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
          },
         username: String
    }
  recipient : {
        id : {
            type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
          },
         username: String
    }
)};
```

If I were to send a message to user y then it would be stored as recipient and the x value would be the sender. When I want to render a page called inbox could i do Messages.find({req.user._id) to sort all messages ? I am a bit lost in regards to the schema design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For schema, you probably want something like this:

```js
const messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  subject: String,
  body: String,
  seen: Boolean,
  sender: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  }
  recipient: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  }
})

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  email: Boolean,
  type: String
})

var Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

For querying, you can find everything you need [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)

Comment: @Ozan, does this answer your question?

Comment: To some extent it does. I am worried whether using such a schema is actually safe.

Comment: Why would it be unsafe?  Keep in mind, you don't need to expose anything in your schema publicly.

Comment: Lets say that user x is viewing a message and the route is app.get('messages/:messageId') would i have to a middleware to check ownership of the message before rendering it to the front ? Otherwise anyone with a message id would be able to read any message right?

Comment: Yes, could use a middleware, however, I would check it in the first line of the handler for 'messages/:messageId'.  We use Passport for user management, it puts the user object onto the request. http://passportjs.org/

Comment: I am using passportjs-local and passportjs-facebook strategies in my project as well. As far as I know it is req.user isn't it? I have defined it as a local currentUser too. However wouldn't anyone who is authenticated could access to a random message with id?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142638/discussion-between-dan-green-leipciger-and-ozan).